# Embedded Linux: Setting up NFS (or any service) in a portable way

Tags: nfs, embedded

If I have a read-only file system, but with a read-write overlay on `/etc`, is it possible to run NFS service (or any other service) via a USB drive, as if the service is a portable application?

Note: the image is bare minimal, with no NFS.